# Javascript password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, passwords

I've a pretty good password validation, but I would like to add some more functionality.

You can see an example here http://jsfiddle.net/yfM5T/22/

Currently I've a password that checks, 7 chars, 1 upper case, 1 digit and 1 special character and even it won't allow white space.

But I want to add

1. password doesn't contains 9 consecutive numbers (because some people use phone numbers as passwords, e.g. it won't take `Pass@123456789` but `Pass123456@789` is ok)
2. Not same as the log-in name
3. Not more than two repeating characters (`saaga` is ok but `saaaga` is not allowed)

Bonus if the password validation tool tip shows the white space validation message only if the user put a white space rather than showing onfocus (only for the white space, 9 consequtive numbers, username etc.)

Comment: Something interesting to think about. The more rules you apply, the more homogenized your passwords become. Then they are easier to brute force. Just saying

Comment: Read: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Because its banking solutions so password rules is very important. My manager decides everything :(..

Comment: If you **must** do this sort of thing (and generally it really irritates me, and causes lots of customer support issues when people forget their passwords), it'd be better to do some general statistical analysis on the characters used instead of applying the sort of "rules" you describe, which probably have no analytical basis for improving security.  Just my opinion :-)

Comment: I think you're crossing the line between securing, and annoying your users. Forcing them to use at least one uppercase or perhaps a number will secure it enough, as long as you're storing them properly on your end. Remember, most people get hacked through social engineering and not actual hacking/brute force attacks. However, if you're just trying to force your users not to use their username, than that's a simple `if` statement. If you don't want them to use phone numbers, use a regular expression.

Comment: show your manager the xkcd @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ posted

Comment: Yeah..Thanks for the valuable info. But we are forcing the user to not enter his username and phone numbers as passwords.

Comment: I think this falls into UI, but I really don't think you should be enforcing mechanicalyl anything but maybe a small length. This is just incredibly annoying to the users. I like to use passphrases, but a lot of sites have stupid restriction that disallow me from using my favorite passphrases.

Comment: Since it's banking: do it in the same way banks do it: Use usernames that are either numbers other people usually don't now or something self-chosen that is not displayed anywhere. After 3 invalid passwords, either block the IP for some time or the account until the owner contacts someone responsible for the system. This is annoying but more secure than any password guidelines - even if someone uses horribly insecure password chances are low someone guesses it within 3 tries.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question?  If you've managed to implement all you say you've implemented, then none of these extra conditions sound like they should even begin to test the limits of your capability.

Comment: Remember you need to do this on the server side as well. Also, your special character verification does not recognize ``_-[]\` as special characters - not sure if they're allowed or if you have a reason for this, but allowing them will increase the potential complexity of passwords and thus _potentially_ security as well - and `/` seems to count as whitespace... not sure why that is

Comment: wow - the characters not allowed didn't come through - strange how the quoting works differently for answers and comments -- the characters that I think should be allowed as special characters (if possible) are: `\``, `-`, `_`, `[`, `]`, and `\ `

Comment: I check and the special characters & working .Thanks for the comment bro!

Answer (score 2):

- 1) `^(?!.*\d{9}.*)`
- 3) `^(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\1\1)`

For the second rule just use a string comparison with the username.